# How to cast a Scala Elem to a NodeSeq

Tags: xml, scala

I am trying to write an XML RewriteRule that will wrap a child element inside a wrapper element in an effort to normalize a bunch of different xml files.  This does what I need it to, but I end up with an Elem and in order to override the `transform()` function, I need to return a NodeSeq.

```
  /* WRAP NODES INSIDE PARENT NODE
   *
   * Some Nodes should be wrapped in an enclosing Node.  For example, some xml versions
   * of the article <contentitem> have <category> as a direct child, but category info  
   * should really have this structure:
   *   <categories>
   *     <category>some category name</category>
   *   </categories>
   */
  val wrapIndividualNodes = new RewriteRule {
    val nodesToWrap = List( ("category", "categories"), ("subcategory", "subcategories") )

    override def transform(n: Node): NodeSeq = {
      for ( (target, wrapper) <- nodesToWrap ) {

        // copy, then delete, children
        val categoryNodes = (n \ target)
        val articleWithoutCategoryNodes = SharedRules.deleteChildren(n, target)

        // wrap children and add as new child
        val categories = <categories>{categoryNodes}</categories>
        SharedRules.addChild(articleWithoutCategoryNodes, categories)

      }
    }
  }
```

**SharedRules.scala**

```
  /**
    * Adds newChild as the last element in the parent node
    */
  def addChild(parent: Node, child: Node): Elem = {
    parent.copy(child = parent.child ++ child)
  }

  /**
    * Deletes all children with matching childLabel from parent
    */
  def deleteChildren(parent: Node, childLabel: String): Elem = {
    parent.copy( child = parent.child.filterNot(_.label == childLabel))
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve there are two way to get a `NodeSeq` from `val elem: Elem`

- do nothing `val ns: NodeSeq = elem` will work since Elem extends Node and Node extends NodeSeq.
- make a singleton Seq `val ns: NodeSeq = elem.theSeq` which will actually wrap your Elem in a Seq[Node] which in turn will be implicitly converted to NodeSeq.

Comment: Huh.  I was looking for something like that in the API, but couldn't find anything: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/scala-xml/#scala.xml.NodeSeq

Comment: Rereading my answer I realise that might not do what you expect because Elem is a Node which extends NodeSeq. So `NodeSeq.fromSeq(elem)` is equivalent to `elem`. I believe you shoud first wrap it in a singleton Seq.

Comment: Using `elem.theSeq` does that and I realise that a `Seq[Node]` will be converted implicitly to a `NodeSeq`